# How Can I obtain PIES/ACES Datasets

Tags: part-identification, parts

Are there any resources out there for obtaining PIES data for an aftermarket part supplier? Or do aftermarket parts manufacturers make their parts catalog available in any other format(other than PDF)? I'm a newbie to all this and have been trying to wrap my head around the ACES and PIES standards and but am missing how an electronics parts catalogs with manufacturer part numbers is actually populated.

Comment: Apparently, you buy a subscription - prices from $1,000 to $15,000 p.a. depending what you want and how big the company is. https://www.autocare.org/data-and-information/data-standards/subscriptions

Comment: Any idea if that includes after market part number data? It is apparent to me that autocare.org provides a database of makes, model, specs & part categories but what I'm really after is how to obtain the data of mapping part numbers to those.